# Vue 3 Web Component - How to use globalProperties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, web-component, vite

I can't figure out how to use globalProperties on a web component.

My main.js looks like this:

```js
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import CoolComponent from './CoolComponent.ce.vue'

const apiBaseUrl = 'https://api.my-domain/public';

axios.defaults.baseURL = apiBaseUrl;

const element = defineCustomElement(CoolComponent, {
  plugins: [VueAxios, axios],
});

customElements.define("my-component", element);
```

I would now like to **define the variable *apiBaseUrl* as a global variable** in main.js,  so I can access *apiBaseUrl* from any component.

In a "regular" app I would solve it like this:

```js
app.config.globalProperties.apiBaseUrl = 'https://api.my-domain/public'
```

But of course that doesn't work in this case.
What is the equivalent of "app...." in this case?

I use Vue 3 + Vite.

How can I best solve this?
I look forward to your feedback!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

### Not possible in Vue 3

> This is a replacement of Vue 2's Vue.prototype which is **no longer present in Vue 3.** As with anything global, this should be used sparingly.

[Source](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties=)

Comment: OK. Here's the case I'm trying to solve: I want to be able to quickly switch between test and production versions of my API endpoints. Now I have to update the URL in several places...this is very cumbersome and error-prone.

But what about app.config.globalProperties.[VAR]? That's actually the principle I'm looking for. It's in the official documentation.

Or would using pinia/VueX be the right way?

Comment: I would reccomend [Env Variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables-and-modes=)

Comment: For sharing configuration, I usually do by creating service module, which is imported in all modules which needs access to common configuration, I have worse problem I want to globally have access to translation function in templates... it seems that you need to manually import in every module `const { t } = useI18n()`   https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/wc.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with [Env-Variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables). To be precise, I used ElMassimo's [vite-plugin-environment plugin](https://github.com/ElMassimo/vite-plugin-environment).
Thanks to [tauzN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3330981/tauzn)